# How to get the value of the last assert statement?

Tags: python, pytest, assert

Is there an easy way to get the value of the last assert as boolean so I can avoid asking for it twice?

Example:

```
assert 1 == 2
status = ???? # how can i get the boolean value of the previous assert
```

I do not want just as i want the nice reporting feature of assert in pytest

```
test = 1 == 2
assert test
```

Comment: `assert` is a statement, not a function, it doesn't return anything, it just checks is the condition is true otherwise it raises AssertionError. You can add custom messages in case the test fails `assert a == b, a == b` It will print `False` if a != b

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If `assert 1 == 2` fails, the code will crash, and `status = <whatever>` will never execute. So if `status = <whatever>` _does_ execute, then you know that the assert succeeded, so you don't need to get its value. Am I missing something?

Comment: I got three wonderful answers that work beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.8, you can use the new [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (walrus operator):

```
>>> assert (test := 1 == 1)
>>> print(test)

True
```

However, note that if the assertion fails, you will not get to the `print` statement because `assert` raises an `AssertionError` exception. If you want to use the value in the error message, you can do following:

```
>>> assert (test := 1 == 2), f"Value was '{test}'."

AssertionError: Value was 'False'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
def f(test):
  try:
    assert test
  except AssertionError:
    return False
```

You could do:

```
f( 1 == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def my_assert(input):
    try:
        assert input
        status = True
    except AssertionError:
        status = False
    return status

my_assert(1 == 2)
```

Comment: i can also do in pytest
```def test_example():